# Input 3 words, Output text with input. What do?

Tags: text, command-line-interface

I want to have a command line function, where I give the input (3 words) and the output is a text file with those words in it.

**Example:**

Input: Cheese; Bacon; Eggs;
Text: I love to eat _____ sandwiches, along with ____ and ____ on a toast.

Output: I love to eat Cheese sandwiches, along with Bacon and Eggs on a toast.

I know this might sound super easy to do, but I honestly don't even know where to begin/what to look for.

I just don't know where to start, so if you could point me to any simple tutorials or functions to get started with, that'd be great.

Cheers,

Comment: What programming language are you wanting to use? If language does not matter, what OS you are using?  Because this could be done in bash on Linux and in Powershell on Windows.

Comment: Powershell Windows, thanks for asking

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not exactly what I was looking for, but it does the trick for me. I was planning to replace words from a tex document (Latex), so establishing variables such as what's explained in this link answers my needs:

[Is there any way I can define a variable in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211888/is-there-any-way-i-can-define-a-variable-in-latex)